# Parsing simple JSON using Ext gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

i'm doing a simple parse of some JSON and it's giving me an error in chrome, what am i missing here?

```
Ext.util.JSON.decode("{info: {synopsis: 'test'}}");
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.json.org/

Think you should use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
Ext.util.JSON.decode('{"info": {"synopsis": "test"}}');
```

Comment: Ah right. I'm used to c#'s json parser which doesn't need quoting.

Comment: So... any reason why it all is so much stricter in the JS world?

Comment: @Chris: The JSON standard states that all keys must be quoted, and that only double quotes are allowed. Less needless variability makes for easier parsing. If the C# parser was written properly it should complain about malformed input.

Comment: Also, can i have newlines or not in my json?

Comment: @Chris: It's not a js rule, it's a json "do it right" rule, as far as I know. Extjs should be expecting a full working string.

Comment: Chris: You'll have to escape them as `\n` (or `\r\n`). Just read the link already, ok?

Comment: @Matti - thanks for the explanation. If that's the way it is, then so be it.

Comment: @Chris: you can, but properly formatted. e.g. a <br> or a \r\n

Answer (score 4):

Be careful if you are using ExtJs 4 onward, You have to use

```
Ext.JSON.decode('{"info": {"synopsis": "test"}}');
```