# Getting runtime error in IE8 using ext-js

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8, runtime-error

I am getting an error in following code which runs perfectly in all browsers except IE8 (not checked with IE9) :

```
doDecode = function(json){
            return eval("(" + json + ")"); //RunTime Error
```

i am getting JavaScript runtime error i.e "syntax error".

Also in many other lines I am getting different kind of runtime errors because of which my app doesn't behave as expected.
(I am using ext-js 3.3.1)
Please help me to resolve this...
Thanks in adv..

(Also wanted to know that is ext-js compatible with IE8 ???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doDecode = function(json){
            return eval ("(" + json + ')');
```

This Worked for me...

source : [link](http://network.org/projects/unimanage/sources/unimanage-main/content/extjs/ext-all-debug.js?rev=21)

Comment: This is just repeating your question?

Comment: Nope. See the ' ' instead of " "

Comment: Ah - subtle: missed that. No idea why that should make a difference though. `eval` is still a risky way to parse JSON though (see my original answer).

Comment: Yes may be.. I will try to find out another way as specified by you. Thanks again...!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's various reasons why parsing JSON using eval is bad. As noted on [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/js.html):

> The eval function is very fast. However, it can compile and execute
>   any JavaScript program, so there can be security issues. The use of
>   eval is indicated when the source is trusted and competent. It is much
>   safer to use a JSON parser. In web applications over XMLHttpRequest,
>   communication is permitted only to the same origin that provide that
>   page, so it is trusted. But it might not be competent. If the server
>   is not rigorous in its JSON encoding, or if it does not scrupulously
>   validate all of its inputs, then it could deliver invalid JSON text
>   that could be carrying dangerous script. The eval function would
>   execute the script, unleashing its malice.

so you'll want to use a JSON parser instead -- again, JSON.org provides one, as well as ones in frameworks such as jQuery and extjs as well -- see this SO question for more info (including examples in the answers): [Parsing simple JSON using Ext gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893714/parsing-simple-json-using-ext-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

but I have used ext in my all the application and not possible to change all the code and replace it with some another parser.
Is there any another alternate ???

Comment: Like I said -- extjs does have one -- see the question I linked to for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the parser available with ExtJS? In ExtJS 3, you should be able to do something like this:

```
jsonObject = Ext.decode(json);
```

This is a shorthand method for the `decode` method in class `Ext.util.JSON`. The method also takes another boolean param to ensure returning null if your json is bad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the change I have given below worked for me, however I am already using the `jsonObject = Ext.decode(json);`
 in my code...

Answer (score 0):

many possible errors, the one that I experienced is the json structure that is sent from the server there is an error, such as excess or shortage of "comma", "{" "}", or "[" "]"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even Ext.decode(json); does not work.
This is because we are not able to identify certain mistake in our code, for which smart browser like FF wont shout.

In that case you can try using Ext.data.JsonStore by directly associating your JSON-string with it.

You may find suitable store over here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore